# Microservices UI

Tags: .net-core, microservices, blazor-webassembly

Let's say we have three microservices, A, B, and C, and we also have a Blazor WASM app that makes calls to these microservices for a simple example.

Suppose we have a single SQL Server database and each microservice has a separate schema with no relationships between schemas.

When service A is called it has to call B, and when service B is called it has to call C. This is done both por read and write operations.

Communication between microservices is done in a decoupled manner by sending messages to a RabbitMq exchange (If this is not possible, then the mode would be request/response)

Questions:

1. How is the information refreshed in the Blazor application if the entire processing cycle has not yet been completed?
2. What is the proper method for presenting and synchronizing information in the Blazor interface?
3. How are processing errors treated and reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a SignalR channel to notify when the task is completed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with push notifications.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).